# Function add two binary numbers in c++

Tags: c++, function, binary, addition

In c++, how I can write a program that read 2 binary numbers then print the result of addition, using a function to read the binary numbers each number has 4-bit, and using a function to add (binary 1, binary 2) ?!

I find this program but I don't want it with arrays, I need it with only functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a[4];
int b[4];
int carry=0;
int result[5];


a[0]=1;
a[1]=0;
a[2]=0;
a[3]=1;

b[0]=1;
b[1]=1;
b[2]=1;
b[3]=1;

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{

    if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==3)
    {
    result[i]=1;
    carry=1;
    }
    if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==2)
    {
    result[i]=0;
    carry=1;
    }
    if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==1)
    {
    result[i]=1;
    carry=0;
    }
    if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==0)
    {
    result[i]=0;
    carry=0;
    }


}
result[4]=carry;
for(int j=4; j>=0; j--)
{
    cout<<result[j];

}
cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you storing the binary digits if not in an array?

Comment: The posted code is full of errors. It goes outside the defined size of the arrays (all three arrays), and the addition resulting in 1 is incorrectly setting the result to 0. And of course, you could do this MUCH simpler using some bitwise operators.

Comment: -1… You want us to do your homework, you found some code online but won't plagiarize it only because it's a mess, there's no mention of how input and output is supposed to happen (all sane computers work in binary!), and you're not even sure if you're required not to use multiple functions.

Comment: @Named good point. `bitset` never came to me on this as I usually rely on `strtol` for this.

Answer (score 0):

there's no such **one function** as unfortunately `std::iostream` and `scanf`-family supports *oct*, *hex*, *dec* but not binary numeric representations.

Basically, use `strtol` and a `itoa`. As the latter is not available on gcc (because it's not ANSI-compliant), I added a snippet of implementation for `itoa`.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

/*CREDIT goes to: http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~slowe/cpp/itoa.html*/
// you should not need this function if compiled smoothly without it
//  ( if you're on Microsoft Visual Studio, you don't need this function
char* itoa(int val, int base){  
    static char buf[33] = {0};  
    int i = 30; 
    for(; val && i ; --i, val /= base)  
        buf[i] = "0123456789abcdef"[val % base];    
    return &buf[i+1];   
}

int main(){
    int a,b;
    char p[100];
    printf("enter your first number:\n");
    scanf("%s",p);
    a = strtol(p,NULL,2);
    printf("enter your second number:\n");
    scanf("%s",p);    
    b = strtol(p,NULL,2);
    printf( itoa( a+b , 2 ) );
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Excellent use of obfuscation to solve a much more complex problem than we need to solve. [And shouldn't buf be 33 long, just in case?]

Comment: @MatsPetersson when I started writing this up, I though a few manipulators from `cin` would do it. Turns out I have to rely on `strtol` and a non-existing `itoa`. (Well if he was on MSVC he probably has `itoa`. Besides, `itoa` and `strtol` is certainly closer to the **one function** requirement (although, two).

Comment: @MatsPetersson Besides I was just copy-pasting from the site credited above for a `itoa` implementation. Surely I prefer *home-making* an array based version. Still, you have to admit that lacking a decent support for binary numeric values is a defect in design.

Comment: Yes, but you could equally write a two or three line function that isn't quite so complicated and using `"digits"[index]` type obfuscation. But I like it, sorry if you took it the wrong way - I hate it when students are given a solution they can just hand to their teacher and the teacher believes they have done the job.

Comment: @MatsPetersson yeah, the `itoa` is not a good KISS example but  a piece of smartly-nasty code. (A similar thread on stackoverflow suggests using **macros** which is more obfuscatorily  technique-demanding.

Comment: `std::bitset` supports binary I/O with `<<` and `>>`. It's only needed for I/O, then `to_ulong` and its conversion construction from `unsigned long` take care of the rest. That's probably what Named was referring to. But none of this is probably allowed in a beginner course, which is what makes the whole question pointless.

Comment: @phoeagon I'm so sorry, my question wasn't clear, excuse me i'm a beginner in c++.. and yea, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: @raya then you need not add that super-complicated `itoa` function into your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

For people doing basic programming in c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int sum(int x, int y)
{
    int r1, r2;
    int carry = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (x != 0 || y != 0)
    {
        r1 = x % 10;
        r2 = y % 10;
        if (r1 == 0 && r2 == 0)
        {
            if (carry == 0)
            {
                sum = sum + ((0) * pow(10, i));
                carry = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sum = sum + ((1) * pow(10, i));
                carry = 0;
            }
        }
        else if ((r1 == 0 && r2 == 1) || (r1 == 1 && r2 == 0))
        {
            if (carry == 0)
            {
                sum = sum + ((1) * pow(10, i));
                carry = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sum = sum + ((0) * pow(10, i));
                carry = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (carry == 0)
            {
                sum = sum + (0 * pow(10, i));
                carry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                sum = sum + ((1) * pow(10, i));
                carry = 1;
            }
        }
        x = x / 10;
        y = y / 10;
        i++;
    }
    if (carry != 0)
    {
        sum = sum + carry * pow(10, i);
    }
    return sum;
}


int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cout << "Enter two binary numbers:";
    cin >> x >> y;
    cout << "The sum of the two numbers is: " << sum(x, y);
}
```